# How isotropic (homogeneous) is the distribution of circular particles

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes

Imagine that we have the spherical particles inside unit cell and we know the coordinates of the centers. Ideally these central points should be distributed isotropically and homogeneously over the unit cell area. However, for some cases this is not suitable assumption, and the arrays of the particles might concentrate along some preferable directions forming so-called chain-like structures.

Let's say that completely random two-dimensional distribution and the case, when all particles lay on one straight line, are the two extreme cases. How for the given set of the coordinates we can estimate the "isotropy" and "homogeneity" of the particle distribution? Could we use some statistic to quantitatively describe this distribution?

Answer (score 1):

A typical approach would be to make a Fourier transformation of the density distribution of particles. In this case, your density distribution $\rho(\vec{r})$ would be a sum over all particles $i$ in the cell that you consider:
$$
\rho(\vec{r}) = \sum_i \delta(\vec{r} - \vec{x}_i)
$$
with $\vec{x}_i$ the location where the $i$th particle is found.

You need a larger number of particles to get a reliable signal out of this before you can conclude that there is or is no(little) structure present.

Essentially this is also what physicists measure in scattering experiments of samples to for instance determine the type of crystal of a material.